# Specific help in showing that Poisson Bracket is part of this Lie Algebra

Tags: derivatives, lie-algebras

Given in this exercise is the following set:
$U = \{f(z) = z^TCz\ \vert\ C \in \textrm{Mat}_{2n}(\mathbb R),\ C^T=C\}$ is a Lie Algebra with $\left\{\cdot , \cdot \right\}$ where
$$
\left\{f,g \right\} = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial q_j} \frac{\partial g}{\partial p_j} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial p_j} \frac{\partial g}{\partial q_j}.
$$

First I computed $\left \{ f,g \right \}$ in this set as follows:

Using $ z=\left( \begin{array}{c} q \\ p \end{array} \right) \in \mathbb R^{2n}$ with $q,p\in \mathbb R^n$, I can write $f(z)= f(q,p) = \begin{pmatrix}q&p\end{pmatrix}\,C\,\begin{pmatrix}p\\q\end{pmatrix}$ and so the derivatives of $f$ are
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_j} &= 2C_{j,k}q_k + 2 C_{j,k+n}p_k,\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_j} &= 2C_{j+n,k}q_k + 2C_{j+n,k+n}p_k.
\end{align*}
(Einstein notation assumed!) Computing the bracket itself gives:
\begin{align*}
\left\{f,g \right\}
=& 4\sum_{j=1}^n \bigg[\left(C_{j,k}q_k + C_{j,k+n}p_k\right)
\left(D_{j+n,l}q_l + D_{j+n,l+n}p_l\right)\\
& - \left(C_{j+n,k}q_k + C_{j+n,k+n}p_k\right)
\left(D-{j,l}q_l + D_{j,l+n}p_l\right)\bigg].
\end{align*}

I think I should be able to find a Matrix K such that, $z^T K z = \left\{f,g\right\}$ to show that the Poisson Bracket is in U... but I can't figure out how to that. Otherwise I could show that the Bracket fulfills the 3 properties of a Lie Algebra ($ \left\{f,f \right\} = 0, \left\{(a+b)f,g \right\} = \left\{af,g \right\} + \left\{bf,g \right\}$ and the Jacobi Identity. But managing those multiple sums is an incredible nuisance and I can't really manage to do that either. I hope someone can set me off in the right direction!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The symmetric  matrix $K$ always exists since the Poisson bracket is again a homogeneous quadratic form.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? How is the Poisson bracket a homogeneous quadratic form?

Comment: It follows from the formula for the Poisson bracket.  Since $f$ is homogeneous  quadratic its partial is homogeneous linear. The same applies for $g$. Therefore the Poisson bracket is homogeneous quadratic.